# How to properly seal water supply line in block foundation

Tags: plumbing, water, sealing, copper

There was an old rag and some very old concrete around this water supply line entering the house.  I would like to reseal it, but I am not sure what to use.

[image: copper water supply line]

Should I use hydraulic cement or something more flexible?

Comment: I would use concrete colored silicone or any silicone would be fine. I would *very carefully* chip away that mortar on top and fill with silicone or other flexible caulk.

Comment: If there is any chance you might damage the pipe in chipping the mortar, then just put calk where you can.

Comment: Thank you.  I plan to pick up a new tube of silicone today to fix it. I was able to chip away the old mortar.